# Xpath where we can do value check for multiple values .//Time[@TOD='Day']//Task[@Status='COMPLETED']

Tags: xpath

I have the below xpath that works on my XML easily when only one status needs to be checked:

```
.//Time[@TOD='Day']//Task[@Status='COMPLETED']
```

What is the way that I would be able to do something like so:

```
.//Time[@TOD='Day']//Task[@Status in 'COMPLETED', 'BLOCKED']
etc
```

Basically status attrib to have a in check rather than an equal to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath 2 or later, if your XPath processor/API supports it, you can use e.g. `.//Time[@TOD='Day']//Task[@Status = ('COMPLETED', 'BLOCKED')]`. In XPath 1.0 use `or` e.g. `.//Time[@TOD='Day']//Task[@Status = 'COMPLETED' or @Status =  'BLOCKED']`.